# Auto-Launch JNLP on click

Tags: java, mime-types, content-type, jnlp

How do I get a JNLP file to auto-launch on click?  (as opposed to clicking save or open when clicked) Is this some type of MIME association that the browser must first recognize?

Comment: Are you opening it from within Chrome?  Chrome does not automatically run JNLPs (most browsers do.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a server configuration file that specifies MIME or content type by file extension.  For JNLP, it should be `application/x-java-jnlp-file`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the other answer is outdated as of today.

**Try changing your link from http:// or https:// to jnlp:// or jnlps://.**

So your url would look something like this: 
jnlp://your.server/path/yourjnlp.jnlp

Caveat: For me, typing this in the Chrome URL doesn't work. It needs to actually be *a link inside the page that gets clicked*. There may also be a Windows requirement but I haven't confirmed that.

See this for more info: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=518170