# How to make java web start launch automatically without double click on the JNLP

Tags: java, google-chrome, java-web-start, jnlp, microsoft-edge

I have a java applet application which is accessed by our customers through our website. Since Microsoft edge and chrome stopped supporting java plug in, we converted the applet to be launched through JNLP and Java Web Start, Unfortunately, In both browsers the JNLP downloaded and the customer should double click the file in order to launch a Java Web Start.

Our customers totally disappointed from this behavior, And I'm trying to find a solution for this issue.

Comment: Does the server provide the correct [content-type for a JNLP](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=content-type+for+a+JNLP&oq=content-type+for+a+JNLP&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.580j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: Yes, Andrew....The server provides the the correct content-type for JNLP, but currently Java Web Start not starting from Microsoft Edge or Google chrome, And the answer you provide for the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556986/auto-launch-jnlp-on-click is valid for that period (2011) but not working now.

Comment: Did you find a solution I am in 2018 for chrome and others  and I have this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Possible solutions

**1)** Change the behavior in the browser to ask the user what to do when he click on a `JNLP link`. Then the user can select `Open with: Java web start launcher` or `save file`.

**edit** It's working in Firefox but it doesn't work with Chrome: see related bug reports [10877](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=10877) and the [open issues](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=jnlp)

**2)** Provide a script to the user which executes
 `javaws https://example.com/your_application.jnlp`

An example for demonstration (application link taken from Oracle tutorial: [Running a Java Web Start Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/running.html))

```
javaws https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/samples/deployment/NotepadJWSProject/Notepad.jnlp
```

This will open a simple Java application.

**edit** For the fearless there is a hacky solution for Chrome.

1. close Chrome, and keep in mind to always make a copy of the files altered in the next steps ;-)
2. find in the Chrome library `chrome.[so|dll]` the bytes `jnlp` and patch them as e.g. `jnl-`
3. find in your Chrome user profile directory the file `Preferences` and amend it as ...

.

```
"download": {
    ...
    "extensions_to_open": "jnlp",
    ...
},
```

Next time you click on a link to a JNLP file it will be opened automatically (with the application which is assigned to open this file type, normally it's `javaws`).

The property was found after having a look into the source [pref_names.cc](https://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/pref_names.cc). But Chrome treat the extension `jnlp` as [dangerous](https://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/browser/download/download_extensions.cc) that's why we need to patch the library as well.

Comment: how can I apply the first point, regarding the example you have mentioned, it's not working from oracle website. moreover, I'm looking for running the Jave Web Start directly, I don't need the customer to see any change, just click on the link and everything will run exactly as he/she run an applet.

Comment: @ManKeer Sorry my fault. Did not pay enough attention for the browsers in question. I amend my answer at least for Chrome. For Microsoft Edge I can't help, don't have it.

Comment: @ManKeer Not a real solution for your customers, but maybe you are anyway interested. Have a look to the "hacky solution" in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your cooperation, but as you said this is totally not a solution for my customers. but really I appreciate your effort for helping

Comment: How to extract the bytes of the chrome.dll

Comment: @ManKeer I did it manually using a binary(aka. hex)-editor.

Comment: Sorry I have nor try this solution. But is is the most practical, real solution, with actual version of chrome? Thanks in advance.