# Web Start JNLP Web Start from javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, java-web-start, jnlp

Can you call a JNLP file from javascript or jquery?

i have an applet i converted to Web Start JNLP. the java process runs in the background. i was calling applet from javascript using DeployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);

how can i call JNLP file without leaving the current page. just launch the java class from jar file?

Comment: *"how can i call JNLP file without leaving the current page."* Put a link in the page to the JNLP file. Ensure the server returns the correct [content-type for JNLP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7556986/418556).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean download JNLP file by javascript? you can simply put

onclick="window.location.href='xxx.jnlp';"

However, you cannot call the web start application from Javascript. It is out of the browser.